# If WooCommerce Product Title Contains "-" It Goes To Next Line

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce, product

this is applicable only on mobile devices, screenshot here:
http://prntscr.com/gtwavv
Found this: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/15763
But I don't want to edit core files as they would be overwritten, any CSS solution available that I can apply?

**EDIT:** I don't want it to go to next line if product title contains "-" I want it on the same line.

Thank you!

Comment: Rather than a screenshot, can you provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: 1. Publish a product with dash/hyphen in title.
2. Check shop page. (not product page)
3. If product contains "-" it shows as in picture attached.

Comment: EDIT: I don't want it to go to next line if product title contains "-" I want it on the same line.

Comment: I think the issue you link to is unrelated, and the only issue is that you just don’t have enough space to display the full title. Check the available space and adjust your CSS. Alternatively, replace the dash with a non-breaking hyphen http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2011/index.htm